# Reference error in d3.js code

Tags: d3.js

I am new to javascript as well as d3. I am running one of the graph codes from the website but I am getting the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null d3.v3.min.js:2
gu                                                          d3.v3.min.js:2
n                                                           d3.v3.min.js:4
e                                                           d3.v3.min.js:4
e                                                           d3.v3.min.js:4
(anonymous function)                                        index.html:44
(anonymous function)                                        d3.v3.min.js:1
t                                                           d3.v3.min.js:1
u                                                           d3.v3.min.js:1

Here's the whole code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

path {
  stroke: #fff;
  fill-rule: evenodd;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 700,
    radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, 2 * Math.PI]);

var y = d3.scale.sqrt()
    .range([0, radius]);

var color = d3.scale.category20c();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + (height / 2 + 10) + ")");

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .startAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x))); })
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.max(0, Math.min(2 * Math.PI, x(d.x + d.dx))); })
    .innerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y)); })
    .outerRadius(function(d) { return Math.max(0, y(d.y + d.dy)); });

d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/d/4063550/flare.json", function(root) {
  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("d", arc)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color((d.children ? d : d.parent).name); })
      .on("click", click);

  function click(d) {
    path.transition()
      .duration(750)
      .attrTween("d", arcTween(d));
  }
});

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", height + "px");

// Interpolate the scales!
function arcTween(d) {
  var xd = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [d.x, d.x + d.dx]),
      yd = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [d.y, 1]),
      yr = d3.interpolate(y.range(), [d.y ? 20 : 0, radius]);
  return function(d, i) {
    return i
        ? function(t) { return arc(d); }
        : function(t) { x.domain(xd(t)); y.domain(yd(t)).range(yr(t)); return arc(d); };
  };
}

</script>
```

Comment: Looks like you not able to get the data, have you tried to console.log it? Just after the d3.json line add console.log(root) and check your console.  If you're not getting the data its because your browser is seeing it as a security risk.  In that case you'll need to store your data locally (in the same directory as code).  You can then use Firefox (I think) or set up a local web server. If you want to set up a local wed server go for python and have a read of [this](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki).

Comment: user1614080, thanks for the response. When you look at the graph here:http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4348373, it really doesn't have any data. But the code still draws the graph. I am using the exact same code.

Answer (score 1):

Around line 44 of `index.html` you can see a possible source of the problem:

```js
d3.json("http://bl.ocks.org/d/4063550/flare.json", function(root) {
  var path = svg.selectAll("path")
      .data(partition.nodes(root))
```

The problem is that the file `http://bl.ocks.org/d/4063550/flare.json` doesn't exist on your domain (which, I am guessing, is `localhost`).

In this case, the `data` is `null` and the `error` is non-null.

As suggested in the comments, try hosting the file locally (or where you are hosting your Javascript code) and it should work.

**To start a local server**

If you have python, then you can start a local webserver which serves static files from the current folder as:

```bash
python -mSimpleHTTPServer
```

This will start a local webserver serving the files in the current folder at `localhost:8000`. You can then point your browser to `http://localhost:8000/the-dowloaded-file.html` to load your webpage which contains this code.

Be sure to change the reference to the file from `http://.../flare.json` to just `flare.json` as well.

Comment: as per your suggestion, I created a local copy on my desktop and the code file is also on my desktop. When I reference the code, it tells me that : XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Desktop/flare.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. Do you think I need to host it on a web server?

Comment: Updated the answer with how to start a local web-server.